# Jquery Mobile + Phonegap the font sizes are different

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an application using Phonegap with Jquery Mobile on Android Platform.

I designed a simple page.  I haven't started any customization yet.  But look at the below screens.

Screen 1: The page launched inside the PhoneGap in my android device
[image: Page loaded inside phonegap]

Screen 2: The same page launched as a .html page in the same android browser
[image: Page loaded in the browser]

See the size variations...  Why it is displaying differently? Do I need to take some standard consideration while designing jQuery mobile pages for Phonegap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens to be within your viewport meta tag?

For example, you might have something similar to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

One of my application I was using this and it seemed to be "Zoomed out" similar to how your application seems.

To solve this, I just changed my viewport meta tag to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: I removed only the "target-densitydpi=device-dpi" and it works fine.

Comment: More on that: http://bowdenweb.com/wp/2011/05/meta-nameviewport-contenttarget-densitydpidevice-dpi.html So, I bet you run into blurry image issue if you let Android scale. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You should use font size in percentage format. that will work in any phonegap app..
example:

```
body{
font-size:200%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use the viewport units, such as vw and vh, which set the font-size of an element relative to the dimensions of the viewport.